# Nested table type in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

How can I define a table type in SQL server when one of the columns is an array of decimals?
I'm trying to pass to stored procedure an .NET object one of the fields of which is an array of decimals.

Thanks

Comment: The normal way is to simply use a separate table.  If you really want, you can use XML.

Comment: or the worst possible solution: comma-delimited values.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff I've added some explanation to my question. Thank you

Comment: @llan . . . Store it as a binary object, if you do not care what the values actually are.

Comment: ... Or serialize it and store as xml :-)

Comment: Check out Erland Sommarskog's page on [Arrays in SQL Server](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html). I feel like I post this link all the time, but it is really useful. He provides some great examples in his section on [XML](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html#XML) too.

Answer (score 3):

t-sql does not support arrays.
You do, however, have some options: here are 3 of them, from the best to the worst:

1. Create 2 table types, have a column in one act as a foreign key to the other.
2. Create a table type with a varchar(max) column that will hold your decimal 
   values as a comma delimited string.
3. Create a table type with an [`xml` data type column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187339.aspx).

Comment: I generally agree, but second is worst (from data handling, performance as size points of view) than third.

Comment: @MatteoSp in this case, you are correct, and I've edited my answer according to your comment. in other cases xml data type might be a more appropriate solution, even when considering it's size overhead.